# Git Integration with phpDesigner on Windows 7

Tags: php, git, windows-7, phpdesigner

How do I configure phpDesigner to synchronize my code with my Git repository.
PS: My OS is Windows 7

Comment: Do you have a Git option in the Tools menu?

Answer (score 0):

phpDesigner itself has no support for GIT build in, but it's compatible with the windows shell and file management, so you can use it together with [msysgit / git for windows](http://msysgit.github.com/).

Comment: answer is obsolete.